# CSS get a layer to go over another layer

Tags: css, html

I have this site here http://willruppelglass.com/Categories.php?action=view

as you can see an image cuts off

I need the div `contentTextWill` to go over `rightSideBar` is this possible?

Here is my code

```
<div class="contentWrapper">
<div class="leftSideBar">
<img class="img-side top" src="images/leftSideTop.jpg" width="169" height="90" border="0" />
<img class="img-side bottom" src="images/leftSideBottom.jpg" width="169" height="90" border="0" />
</div><!--leftSideBar-->

<div class="content" id="content">
<div class="topContent">

<div class="contentTextWill">
</div><!---This Div needs to go over... --->

<div class="bottomContent">
</div><!--bottomContent-->
</div><!--content-->

<div class="rightSideBar">
<img class="img-side top" src="images/rightSideTop.jpg" width="169" height="90" border="0" />
<img class="img-side bottom" src="images/rightSideBottom.jpg" width="169" height="90" border="0" />
</div><!--rightSideBar--> <!---Over this div --->

</div><!--contentWrapper-->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move `.rightSideBar` above the `.content` in DOM:

```
<div class="contentWrapper">
<div class="leftSideBar">
<img class="img-side top" src="images/leftSideTop.jpg" width="169" height="90" border="0" />
<img class="img-side bottom" src="images/leftSideBottom.jpg" width="169" height="90" border="0" />
</div><!--leftSideBar-->

<div class="rightSideBar">
<img class="img-side top" src="images/rightSideTop.jpg" width="169" height="90" border="0" />
<img class="img-side bottom" src="images/rightSideBottom.jpg" width="169" height="90" border="0" />
</div><!--rightSideBar--> <!--- Over this div, not any more --->

<div class="content" id="content">
<div class="topContent">

<div class="contentTextWill">
</div><!---This Div needs to go over... --->

<div class="bottomContent">
</div><!--bottomContent-->
</div><!--content-->

</div><!--contentWrapper-->
```